# Как правильно реализовать циклический метод сдвига вправо на 1 символ Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

Покажите, пожалуйста, реализацию метода с помощью swap посимвольно (или replace).

> в задании нужно реализовать циклический метод сдвига вправо на 1 символ (то есть последний символ на первое место).

Суть в том, что в программу я ввожу строку символов, элементы которой в последствии сдвигаю. Попробовал таким методом, но результат после компиляции не тот, который нужен.

```
public String row2(String row) { // сдвиг вправо на 1 элемент
    char[] m = row.toCharArray();
                int n = 1;
                String swappedString = "";
                for (int i = m.length-n; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if(i+n >= row.length()){
                        m[i+n-row.length()] = m[i];
                    }
                    else{
                        m[i+n] = m[i];
                        swappedString +=m[i];
                    }
                }
                return   swappedString;
        }
```

UPD: добавил методы в реализации

```
1)      public String swappedString(String row) { 
            String row3 = row.charAt(row.length() - 1) + row.substring(0, 
            row.length() - 1);
            return row3;
        }



2)      public String swappedString(String row) { 
                int cursor = row.length() - 1;    
                return row.substring(cursor) + row.substring(0, cursor);
                 }
```

Comment: "результат не тот, который нужен" - а какой? что например?

Comment: Так и поставьте последний символ на первое место в результате, а затем в цикле от `0` до `row.length() - 1` добавляйте символы из `row` в `swappedString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень простое решение:

```
String row = row.charAt(row.length() - 1) + row.substring(0, row.length() - 1);
```

Comment: Благодарю, Вас. Действительно, отличное решение, проверил, все окей.
А swap как-то можно реализовать такое?

Comment: @invzbl3 свап лучше делать через массив символов или StringBuilder. Т.к. String неизменяемый объект, на любое изменение создается новый объект. Т.е. в примере выше создается 3 объекта строки.

Comment: @Виктор, и зачем же в сложении двух строк использовать StringBuilder?

Comment: @Qwertiy вопрос был про свап а там уже больше строк будет.

Comment: @Виктор понял, спасибо,

Answer (score 2):

Если не сильно менять ваш код, то 2мя циклами.

```
public String cycle(String row) { // сдвиг вправо на 1 элемент
    char[] m = row.toCharArray();
    int n = 1;
    char[] result = new char[m.length];
    for (int i = 0; i<m.length - n; i++) {
        result[i+n] = m[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        result[i] = m[m.length - n + i ];
    }

    return new String(result);
}
```

если использовать методы класса `String`, то можно сделать проще

```
public String substring(String row) { // сдвиг вправо на 1 элемент
    int move = 1;
    int cursor = row.length() - move;
    return row.substring(cursor) + row.substring(0, cursor);
}
```

Comment: Во втором способе у вас получился сдвиг влево на 1.

Comment: @naXa спасибо, поправил

Comment: спасибо,Виктор, получилось. Только со строчкой int move = 1 смещалось на два вправо,а не на 1. И в 3й строчке убрал n-ку и добавил скобки после length

Comment: @invzbl3 да, пару ошибок допустил, писал сразу в комментарий. Ответ поправил

Answer (score 1):

**Вот попробуй это!**

Принцип прост: ты читаешь в цикле каждый символ, но место добавления его справа в `lineNew` (чтобы не получилось та же строчка, что и изначально), ты добавляешь символ слева `line.charAt(i) + lineNew`

```
public class stack {
    public String replace(String line) {
        String lineNew = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            lineNew = line.charAt(i) + lineNew;
        }
        return lineNew;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        stack teStack = new stack();
        System.out.println(teStack.replace("dance"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Если я верно понял автора, то ему надо сдвинуть символы, а не перевернуть строку.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать примерно такой метод:

```
String rotate(String s, int shift) {
    if ((shift %= s.length()) == 0) return s;
    int finalShift = shift < 0 ? shift + s.length() : shift;
    return IntStream.range(0, s.length())
        .map(i -> (i - finalShift + s.length()) % s.length()).map(s::charAt)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

При положительных значениях `shift` выполняется сдвиг вправо, при отрицательных, соответственно, влево.

Answer (score 0):

Как насчёт такого решения (Java 8)?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
...

public static String rightShift(String row) {
    List<Character> chars = row.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.rotate(chars, 1);
    String result = chars.stream().map(e->e.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining());

    return result;
}
```